# .NET Core MVC Foreign Key Issue MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using MySQL via Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL: 1.1.0.

What I am running into is an issue with how foreign keys are done in EF Core. Below is the item I'm trying to get into a table that maps an entity to a harvestable.

```
public class HarvestItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HarvestableID")]
    public Harvestables Harvestable { get; set; }

    public int HarvestableID { get; set; }

    public bool IsHarvestable { get; set; }
}
```

The class that composes a list of HarvestItem is defined as shown below.

```
class Harvester 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...Other Miscellaneous Attributes...

    public virtual List<HarvestItem> Harvestables { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to call the following code, I get a primary key violation exception.

```
if (myHarvester.ID == 0)
     _context.Harvester.Add(myHarvester);
else
     _context.Harvester.Update(myHarvester);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The exception simply says it cannot insert a record with an ID of 1, because of a primary key violation. Am I doing this incorrectly? How can I get my relationship to have a Harvester table, with a cross reference table to tie my HarvestItems between two entities (Harvester and EntityItem)?

Comment: Just a thought have set the ID column as an auto-increment column?

Comment: Yes, all of them are auto-incrementing.

Comment: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` have you tried this. To be honest never used attribute (always used fluent)

Comment: yes Nico, I've tried that, and that's not what seems to be the issue. It seems to be trying to add the Harvestable to the db again, since the HarvestItem references the Harvestable, when I add my Harvester, it has a collection of HarvestItems, that encapsulate the Harvestables, which is  (Harvestables) really just a look up table of values.

Comment: Are you sure Pomelo have identity-column support?

Comment: Yes, I can see the tables that are created in MySQL workbench, and other entity objects I have in the db have identity columns that work just fine. Again, I think the issue is it's trying to insert into Harvestables, which isn't meant to be inserted into, it's a lookup table.